# How to drive a 4bit GLCD?

Tags: library, lcd, display

i've got a huge (about 6 x 23 cm) graphics LCD. I used my multimeter and the datasheet the LCD driver chips (6 x KS0104 and 2 x KS0103) to get the pinout. It has the following pins: GND, M, FCS (not 100% shure), CL1, CL2, D0-3, VDD and a ground for the metal part.

My problem is that i dont know how i can drive a 4bit GLCD with an Arduino because i didnt found a library which can do this (e.g. OpenGLCD supports only the KS0104 which is an 8 bit controller)

Comment: What type of Arduino? A driver for that will require a lot of memory.

Comment: I already got an UNO but if it is necessary i could buy a MEGA (if it works).

Comment: How large is the LCD? Number of pixels. According to the product description (KS0104) it is 4-bit per pixel (16 levels gray-scale). Is that correct?

Comment: i counted about 17 pixels on 1 cm so this should be something like 391x138

Comment: That gives a total of 54K pixels. And with 4-bit per pixel, two pixels in a byte, 27K byte to store a packed off-screen bitmap. Even an Arduino Mega would have too little memory for that. This might explain why there are no supporting library for that device.

Comment: You might be right but i think i could also buy a DUE or ZERO (if necessary) and the main problem is not the amount of pixels, it is the 4bit connection (which is not supported by any GLCD library).

Comment: I copy-pasted @MikaelPatel comment as an answer. Please, accept it to close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MikaelPatel answered your question in the comments:

> That gives a total of 54K pixels. And with 4-bit per pixel, two pixels
>   in a byte, 27K byte to store a packed off-screen bitmap. Even an
>   Arduino Mega would have too little memory for that. This might explain
>   why there are no supporting library for that device.